# How can I read values of a variable in a netcdf file in python?

Tags: python, variables, netcdf

I have a NetCDF file called `air.sig995.2012.nc`. it has four variables :
`('lat','lon','time','air')`.

I am trying to read the values of any of the variables, lets say the variable `air` using below line:

```
import scipy.io.netcdf as S
fileobj=S.netcdf_file('air.sig995.2012.nc','r')
data=fileobj.variables['air'].getValue()
```

but it gives me below error:

> ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar

I am fairly new to python. Can anyone help me on this one.

Comment: Is there any reason why you use `scipy.io.netcdf` instead of `NetCDF4` or `xarray`? I think that Scipy's NetCDF stuff is pretty old...

Comment: Use xarray as @bart mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not xarray, you can do this with the netcdf4-python library with the same slice syntax:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset

nc = Dataset('air.sig995.2012.nc')
my_array = nc.variables['air'][:]
```

Answer (score 0):

The output you're expecting is quite ambiguous but both methods should work depending on your specific goal in mind.

```
`import xarray as xr `
### open netcdf file ###
df = xr.open_dataset('path/file.nc')

### extract values of variable 'air' ####
air = df['air'][:]
air_flat = df['air'].values.flatten() # 1-d data
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.